# Jquery selector attribute variable string concatenation

Tags: jquery, variables, attributes

im trying to use a varibale as a selector attribute

when I use it this way it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a2").click(function(){
    x = $("#a2").attr("alt");

    $("[alt=ab][name=mmm]").attr("src", "http://www.polygon.com");
  });
});
```

but when I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a2").click(function(){
    x = $("#a2").attr("alt");

    $("[alt='x'][name=mmm]").attr("src", "http://www.polygon.com");
  });
});
```

it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x is not being substituted.

```
$("[alt="+x+"][name=mmm]").attr("src", "http://www.polygon.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change your quotes and concatenate the string.

```
$('[alt=' + x + '][name=mmm]').attr("src", "http://www.polygon.com");
```

Comment: @user3912129 great! please select either my or Alan's answer ( we both put the same thing ), so other people who find this question know that you were able to resolve the issue!